# Want to setup a voice-to-voice communication service/group call service on rails. Where should I start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have a fair bit of experience making rails applications, but I have never really tried to make an application with the use of a microphone. I don’t need to have video call, only voice, but I would want to control how many people could connect to a single call. Also I would like it to not have to do with actual phone numbers, but have a completely separate service like skype.  Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial rails app, but just from googling I found Adhearsion

Check it out: http://www.adhearsion.com/

> Adhearsion is a full-featured framework for the development of
>   applications which interact with or control voice communications.